# Grid itemrenderer messup while scrolling

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I have one list which have Datagrid as `itemRenderer` like:

```
<s:List id="cList" itemRenderer="views.renderers.DGridItemRenderer" 
                    dataProvider="{sList}" useVirtualLayout="false"/>
```

And ItemRenderer Datagrid is like:

```
<s:DataGrid id="cDataGrid" width="100%" height="100%" editable="true" >
<s:columns>
 <mx:ArrayList>
  <mx:source>
    <s:GridColumn width="40" headerText="Name" dataField="name" editable="false"/>
    <s:GridColumn width="40" headerText="class" dataField="class" editable="false" />
    <s:GridColumn width="60" headerText="age" dataField="age" editable="true"/>
    <s:GridColumn width="60" headerText="SLight" editable="false" itemRenderer="views.renderers.SLColorStatusRenderer"/>
  </mx:source>
  </mx:ArrayList>
 </s:columns>   
</s:DataGrid>
```

Now `Slight` gridColumn have following `GridItemRenderer` which have icon :

```
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" verticalCenter="0" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {

    if(data.age < 18 && data.age > 0)
    {
      imgStatus.source = ImageProvider.redIcon;
    }
    else if(data.age >= 18)     
    {
      imgStatus.source = ImageProvider.greenIcon;   
    }        

  ]]>
  </fx:Script>
   <s:Image id="imgStatus" width="21" height="21" buttonMode="true" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" />
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

SLight column contained Red/Green icon depend on data of age. Age value should be editable in datagrid.

If Age lessthan 18 then red else green icon.

Now, My issue is that When i scroll datagid, icon will mess-up. Icon will display in any record wheather there is age or not.

When load first time all icon looks good. But when i scroll then only mess-up icon and chnage their position.

I use `useVirtualLayout="false"` for list and `clipAndEnableScrolling="true"` for `itemrenderer` but still i can't solve it.

I found lot but didn't get any proper solution.

**Edit:**

If age less then 18 then red, Else if age greater 18 then green. Other wise if not age defined then blank.

My issue is when i scroll then blank row will also display icon. and red icon row will change to green and green to red randomly. All messup.

First it shows like following. (it's correct):

[image]

After when i scroll datagrid it change to following. (it's in-correct)

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly: replace else with `else if(data.age >= 18)`

Comment: Possible itemRenderer recycling issue? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308385/flex-datagrid-row-color-spreads-when-scrolled-up-down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308385/flex-datagrid-row-color-spreads-when-scrolled-up-down)

Comment: I had trouble reading this question; I'm not sure what you mean.  Is the `imgStatus` icon supposed to be there for every row?  Your code says it should, but your question implies it shouldn't.  Or is the color of the icon wrong for some rows when you scroll?  Finally - could you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @user2836288 you right if it's greater then 18 then green else not.

Comment: @Brian I have edited question. If age less then 18 then red, Else if age greater 18 then green. Other wise if not age defined then blank.

Comment: @kaarto I alerady applied that solution but not success.

Comment: @Brian My issue is when i scroll  then blank row will  also display icon. and red icon row will change to green and green to red randomly.

Comment: If you have for example 3 lines visible, let say green, red and green, and you scroll 3 rows down, are the icons on next three lines also in order green, red and green?

Comment: @ketan The "else blank" part isn't in your code.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you mentioned `useVirtualLayout` and `clipAndEnableScrolling` - those have nothing to do with this sort of problem.

Comment: @kaarto No. it's in random order. Suppose i have 3 rows. green, red and green and when i scroll then another three line have random color icons and also above three lines will change the color.

Comment: @Brian else is not required if there is not match condition then doesn't diplay any icon.

Comment: I don't think you understand item renderers.  When you scroll, you're not getting rid of lines that scroll off the screen and creating new ones that scroll on the screen -- you're taking the one from the top and moving it to the bottom, and setting new values on it.  So if you don't have the "else" clause, you're not saying "put nothing there", you're actually saying "leave whatever was already there".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not handling itemrenderer recycling properly, given that `age` is not always set.  You'd be okay if your data always had an `age` value.  As it is, your code doesn't have a way to blank out the `imgStatus` object -- it just leaves whatever icon was already there if `age` is `null` or `-1`.

Change your code to the following:

```
if(data.age < 18 && data.age > 0)
{
    imgStatus.source = ImageProvider.redIcon;
    imgStatus.visible = true;
}
else if(data.age >= 18)     
{
    imgStatus.source = ImageProvider.greenIcon;   
    imgStatus.visible = true;
}
else
{
    //You could use the following line instead if you have a "clear icon" defined.
    //imgStatus.source = ImageProvider.clearIcon;
    imgStatus.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but will not solve my issue. And i have not clear icon defined. I just doesn't give source to image so it stay blank. I tried this solution to make visible false in else. But still have issue. I have add image in my question How it looks.